# Al presionar atras no vuelve de la forma esperada

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

Si hago un recorrido por mi app y voy pasando entre los layouts, al ir dando al botón atrás del terminal móvil, veo que esté no va hacia atrás como lo espero, si no que vuelve atrás en el camino que yo he realizado en la app, pasando así por todos los layouts que he pasado, hasta al final salir de la app.

A ver si puedo explicarme bien..Supongamos que esto es un resumen de mis layouts en la app

```
Main
    layout1
        layout1.1
        layout1.2
    layout2
        layout2.1
    layout3
    layout4
```

Yo entro en la aplicación y hago este recorrido:

> Main -> layout1 -> Layout1.1 -> Layout1.2 -> Main -> layput2 -> layout

Al darle atrás en ese último punto en el que el usuario se encuentra lo que hace la aplicación es pasar por absolutamente todos los layouts que ha visitado. Es decir:

> Layout2 -> Main -> layout1.2 -> layout1.1 -> Layout1 - Main

Al darle al botón atrás del terminal movil me gustaría que esté donde esté vaya al layout que esté atrás jerárquicamente y no que vuelva a pasar por absolutamente todos los layouts que haya visitado el usuario

**EDITO:**

Vale, me he dado cuenta de me pasa esto porque en los layoutX.X se vuelve a la página anterior no por el botón atrás del movil, si no porque tengo un botón en ese activity que al darle se ejecuta un Intent al layout anterior, y por eso luego al darle atrás hace todo ese recorrido.

¿ Hay alguna forma SIMULAR que le doy al botón atrás pero para hacerlo al darle a un botón y no hacerlo mediante el Intent ?

Comment: Puedes dar vistazo a la documentación oficial https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral

Comment: Tambien la guia de MAterial Design sobre navegación https://material.io/design/navigation/understanding-navigation.html#reverse-navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale encontré la solución yo mismo, la publico por si algún novato se encuentra con el mismo problema.

```
onBackPressed();
```

onBackPressed() es lo mismo que darle al botón atrás de nuestro terminal móvil

Comment: Si onBackPressed() sirve para ir atrás pero también existe usar NavUtils que si tienes una app que es llamada por otra y quieres que el usaurio si da atrás con el botón virtual vaya a un subapartado de tu app, pero si el usuario pulsa atrás con el botón fisico/barra navegación vaya atrás a la app que la invocada.

Comment: Muy útil, lo tendré en cuenta, gracias @Webserveis